# Returning Value from a Function that has Chain Ajax Requests in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a chained Ajax requests in my function.
Function A and B are Ajax requests. A will run first and B will run after A returns its data.

My problem is that Function C is the one that executes Function B. When Function C is executed, a button that executes C will be disabled temporarily until A && B is finished.

How do I return a value on function c below?

I need to return true on the function c **AFTER** function a & b requests completed returning data.

I'm thinking if I return true on the callback function inside done(), fail() or always(), the value will return to the callback function and not to the c().

```
function a(methodA) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "api/a",
        cache:false,
        data: { method: methodA },
        dataType: "json",
    });
}

function b(methodB) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "api/b",
        cache:false,
        data: { method: methodB },
        dataType: "json",
    });
}

function c(data) {
    a(data)
    .done(function(data2) {
        b(data2)
        .done(function(data3) {

        })
        .fail(function(data3) {

        })
        .always(function(data3) {

        })
    })
    .fail(function(data3) {

    })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnC').click(function(event) {
        $('#btnC').prop('disabled', true);
        var c = c(getData);
        if(c == true) {
            $('#btnC').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the return value of `c` to be dependent on asynchronous callbacks you can't just return a value. You have to return a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) because the value you want to return is timed based on the asynchronous requests made by the 2 ajax calls (not available when return is called). Therefor you can promise the return of a value but cannot give the value right away.

```js
function a() {
  // mock request since content doesn't matter
  return $.get('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js');
}

function b(fail) {
  // google does not allow cross origin requests
  if (fail) return $.get('https://google.com');

  return a();
}

function c(failB) {
  let requests = [
    Promise.resolve( a() ),
    Promise.resolve( b(failB) ),
  ];
  
  return Promise
    .all(requests)
    .then(results => Promise.resolve(true))
    .catch(error => Promise.reject('one or multiple requests failed'));
}

c().then(result => {
  console.log(result);
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});

c(true).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Returning just the value `true` might be a bit useless, since if the promise is resolved you know everything succeeded. You could just simply leave out that part and the `results` will be passed on as result of the `c` promise. The same goes for the error message. In the above code I don't use the error itself but instead generate my own string. If you are more interested in the failing object you could leave out this `catch` in `c`. See the example below.

```js
function a() {
  // mock request since content doesn't matter
  return $.get('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js');
}

function b(fail) {
  // google does not allow cross origin requests
  if (fail) return $.get('https://google.com');

  return a();
}

function c(failB) {
  let requests = [
    Promise.resolve( a() ),
    Promise.resolve( b(failB) ),
  ];
  
  return Promise.all(requests);
}

c().then(results => {
  // in this case has 2 the same values since the same url is requested
  results.forEach(resp => console.log(resp.substring(0, 15)));
}).catch(jqXhr => {
  console.log(jqXhr.statusText);
});

c(true).then(results => {
  results.forEach(resp => console.log(resp.substring(0, 15)));
}).catch(jqXhr => {
  console.log(jqXhr.statusText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Ajax method returns a promise object. (To be exact, `jqXHR`)
Usually, it uses like this.

```
var result =
    $.post("url").done(function() {
        // after ajax.
    });

// called when ajax process done finished.
result.promise().done(function() {
    // blah blah blah
});
```

However, when it comes to a nested ajax, you need to more work than usual.
Use `then()` and return `inner ajax`.

```
function callAjaxs() {
    return $.get("ajaxA").then(function(res) {
        return $.get("ajaxB", res).done(function() {
            // blah blah blah
        });
    });
}

// call function and use promise. (of course, you can also use fail, always)
callAjaxs().promise().done(function() {
    // $('#btnC').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

If you don't care about details, I think this way is a good option.